# Error in map function in JavaRDD.map

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am using spark to implement LDA model , I am not able to forward while I am stuck at an error in the map function. Here is my code and someone please help me what is the problem in map function.

```
JavaRDD<Tuple3<Long, int[], double[]>> result=sameModel.javaTopTopicsPerDocument(3);
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object,Integer>> finalresult =  result.map(      

        new  Function <Tuple3<Object, int[], double[]>, Tuple2< Object, Integer >>(){

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public Tuple2<Object, Integer> call(Tuple3<Object, int[], double[]> tuple) throws Exception { 
                 return (new Tuple2<>((Object)tuple._1(),(Integer)tuple._2()[0]));

             }

        }

        );
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Input argument should be `Tuple3<Long, int[], double[]>` but it is  `<Tuple3<Object, int[], double[]>`
Fixed the issue when i changed that